# Applying Haskell map function in recursion

Tags: dictionary, haskell, recursion, backtracking

Recently I've been doing some Haskell. I need to generate all possibilities of strings, that is I am given `[String]`, I should output `[[String]]`.

```
solveGame :: [String] -> [[String]]
solveGame ts = recGame [] ts
  where recGame xs [] = [xs]
        recGame xs (t:ts) = map (recGame (xs ++ ) ts) [[x] | x <- (gen t)]
```

where, `gen` outputs number of all possible strings to recur, therefore,
`gen :: String -> [String]`. So basically the problem is to permute all possible strings, generated by `gen`. I tried to run my version, but it outputs the errors. Is it alright to do it in this way?

Input for `solveGame` will be matrix n*n of stars
(for example `["**", "**"]`) and the output should be list of all possible matrices filled with 1 and 0 (this list will will contain 16 matrices like `["10", "01"]`)

The errors that I have:

```
Takuzu.hs:15:16: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[[String]]’
                  with actual type ‘[String] -> [a1]’
    • Probable cause: ‘recGame’ is applied to too few arguments
      In the expression: recGame [] ts
      In an equation for ‘solveGame’:
          solveGame ts
            = recGame [] ts
            where
                recGame xs [] = [xs]
                recGame xs (t : ts)
                  = map (recGame (xs ++) ts) [[...] | x <- (gen t)]
   |
15 | solveGame ts = recGame [] ts
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Takuzu.hs:15:24: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[a1] -> [a1]’
                  with actual type ‘[a0]’
    • In the first argument of ‘recGame’, namely ‘[]’
      In the expression: recGame [] ts
      In an equation for ‘solveGame’:
          solveGame ts
            = recGame [] ts
            where
                recGame xs [] = [xs]
                recGame xs (t : ts)
                  = map (recGame (xs ++) ts) [[...] | x <- (gen t)]
   |
15 | solveGame ts = recGame [] ts
   |                        ^^

Takuzu.hs:16:9: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[a]’ with ‘[a] -> [a]’
      Expected type: ([a] -> [a]) -> [String] -> [String] -> [a]
        Actual type: [a] -> [String] -> [[a]]
    • In an equation for ‘solveGame’:
          solveGame ts
            = recGame [] ts
            where
                recGame xs [] = [xs]
                recGame xs (t : ts)
                  = map (recGame (xs ++) ts) [[...] | x <- (gen t)]
    • Relevant bindings include
        recGame :: ([a] -> [a]) -> [String] -> [String] -> [a]
          (bound at Takuzu.hs:16:9)
   |
16 |   where recGame xs [] = [xs]
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
Failed, no modules loaded.
```

Comment: "it outputs the errors" -- Please include these errors in your question, it will help us answer it.

Comment: You’ve included lots of irrelevant errors, but the main error here seems to be that you’ve used a `recTakuzu` function but have not defined it.

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, and it is still not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error message, it looks like GHC is inferring the wrong type for `recGame`. (How do I know this? It’s because every time `recGame` is mentioned in the error messages, there’s a lot of `[a] -> [a]` stuff, which doesn’t look right.) So, as a first step, let’s add a type signature:

```hs
solveGame :: [String] -> [[String]]
solveGame ts = recGame [] ts
  where 
    recGame :: [String] -> [String] -> [[String]]
    recGame xs [] = [xs]
    recGame xs (t:ts) = map (recGame (xs ++ ) ts) [[x] | x <- (gen t)]
```

Once we do this, we get some more useful error messages:

```
so.hs:10:30: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[String] -> [String]’
                  with actual type ‘[[String]]’
    • Possible cause: ‘recGame’ is applied to too many arguments
      In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(recGame (xs ++) ts)’
      In the expression: map (recGame (xs ++) ts) [[x] | x <- (gen t)]
      In an equation for ‘recGame’:
          recGame xs (t : ts) = map (recGame (xs ++) ts) [[x] | x <- (gen t)]
   |
10 |     recGame xs (t:ts) = map (recGame (xs ++ ) ts) [[x] | x <- (gen t)]
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

so.hs:10:39: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘[String]’
                  with actual type ‘[String] -> [String]’
    • In the first argument of ‘recGame’, namely ‘(xs ++)’
      In the first argument of ‘map’, namely ‘(recGame (xs ++) ts)’
      In the expression: map (recGame (xs ++) ts) [[x] | x <- (gen t)]
   |
10 |     recGame xs (t:ts) = map (recGame (xs ++ ) ts) [[x] | x <- (gen t)]
   |                                       ^^^^^
```

So, it looks like in the `(t:ts)` case, you’re giving `(xs++)` as a parameter to `recGame` — but `(xs++)` is a function, so you can’t do that! I don’t know what you’re trying to do here, so I can’t suggest a fix, but that is definitely the error, and it’s one you should fix.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is to permute list of string, that is ["*", "*"] , where * should be substituted by "1" or "0", and it should output [["0", "0"], ["0", "1"], ["1", "0"], ["1", "1"]] and I already have a function for permuting string

Comment: @stackoverload I’m not sure I understand. Could you give an example of how you would call `recGame`, and the expected result?

Comment: I added input and output of the program